# How can I write a PowerShell alias with arguments in the middle?

Tags: powershell, g++, alias

I'm trying to set up a Windows PowerShell alias to run MinGW's g++ executable with certain parameters. However, these parameters need to come after the file name and other arguments. I don't want to go through the hassle of trying to set up a function and all of that. Is there a way to simply say something like:

```
alias mybuild="g++ {args} -lib1 -lib2 ..."
```

or something along those lines? I am not all that familiar with PowerShell, and I'm having a difficult time finding a solution. Anyone?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You want to use a function, not an alias, as Roman mentioned. Something like this:

```
function mybuild { g++ $args -lib1 -lib2 ... }
```

To try this out, here's a simple example:

```
PS> function docmd { cmd /c $args there }
PS> docmd echo hello
hello there
PS>
```

You might also want to put this in your profile in order to have it available whenever you run PowerShell. The name of your profile file is contained in `$profile`.

Comment: a little improvement to get an better accessible for commands is to use New-Alias to map an Alias to the new function.  
`Function SCP-Filetransfer { cmd /c pscp.exe -i ~\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk $args }
    New-Alias -Force pscp SCP-Filetransfer`

Comment: The downside of this is no parameter completion is available on the function

Comment: You can use the Alias attribute inside your function instead of creating a New-Alias for the function:

`function MyFunction {[Alias('mf')] param($Param) Write-Output $Param}`

Answer (score 6):

A few years ago I created a PowerShell module that does this. It is on the gallery and it is open source.

I was looking for the same experience. This is how to use it:

```
Add-Alias ls 'ls -force'
Add-Alias add 'git add'
```

Gallery:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/posh-alias/

Github:
https://github.com/giggio/posh-alias

Comment: What is the difference to the built in New-Alias? `New-Alias ll 'dir'`?

Answer (score 5):

There is not such a way built-in. IMHO, a wrapper function is the best way to go so far. But I know that some workarounds were invented, for example:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120213013609/http://huddledmasses.org/powershell-power-user-tips-bash-style-alias-command

Comment: A bash alias really is more closely synonymous with a PowerShell function or cmdlet. An alias in PowerShell is really just used for shortening an existing function/cmdlet - such as the alias `rm` for Remove-Item.

Comment: the issue with functions is their ungodly overhead in Powershell.

Answer (score 4):

To build an function, store it as an alias, and persist the whole thing in your profile for later, use:

```bsh
$g=[guid]::NewGuid();
echo "function G$g { COMMANDS }; New-Alias -Force ALIAS G$g">>$profile
```

where you have replaced `ALIAS` with the alias you want and `COMMANDS` with the command or string of commands to execute.

Of course, instead of doing that you can (and should!) make an alias for the above by:

```bsh
echo 'function myAlias {
    $g=[guid]::NewGuid();
    $alias = $args[0]; $commands = $args[1]
    echo "function G$g { $commands }; New-Alias -Force $alias G$g">>$profile
}; New-Alias alias myAlias'>>$profile
```

Just in case your brain got turned inside out from all the recursion (aliasing of aliases, etc.), after pasting the second code block to your PowerShell (and restarting PowerShell), a simple example of using it is:

```bsh
alias myEcho 'echo $args[0]'
```

or without args:

```bsh
alias myLs 'ls D:\MyFolder'
```

### Iff you don't have a profile yet

The above method will fail if you don't have a profile yet!
In that case, use `New-Item -type file -path $profile -force` [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8997378/1739000).

Comment: Using this (and all other _alias via function_ approaches) fails when it comes to piping input into the aliased command. Test case: `ps | grep` where `grep` is an alias that works fine. Where `grep` is a function, the above hangs indefinitely. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @ehiller, I'm not able to duplicate your issue, but my functions were designed to be used with arguments, not pipelines.

Comment: I like the basic idea of your approach, but the implementation is unnecessarily complex: there is no need to create a PowerShell alias at all, via an aux. function -just _define a function directly_, with the desired "alias" name.

Comment: @mklement0 isn't that what ehiller's complaint was about above?

Comment: No, ehiller's complaint is about lack of pipeline support, which is an unrelated problem - and not necessarily one that needs to be solved in the context of the question at hand. Your solution inspired [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55708770/45375) - please note the comments - and I've tried to show in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707452/45375) how to do it the PowerShell-idiomatic way.

Comment: Why make everything so difficult and convulated?

Answer (score 4):

This is a sample function that will do different things based on how it was called:

```
Function Do-Something {
[CmdletBinding()] 
[Alias('DOIT')]
Param(
    [string] $option1,
    [string] $option2,
    [int] $option3)
#$MyInvocation|select *|FL
If ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq 'DOIT'){write-host "You told me to do it...so i did!" -ForegroundColor Yellow}
Else {Write-Host "you were boring and said do something..." -ForegroundColor Green}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a 'filter' is also an option, a [lighter alternative to functions](https://4sysops.com/archives/the-powershell-filter-2). <sup><sub>([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230803213156/https://4sysops.com/archives/the-powershell-filter-2/))</sub></sup>

It processes each element in the pipeline, assigning it the $_ automatic variable. So, for instance:

```
filter test { Write-Warning "$args $_" }
'foo','bar' | test 'This is'
```

returns:

```
WARNING: This is foo
WARNING: This is bar
```

Comment: thank you for this insight!

Answer (score 0):

I use wrapper functions with an alias:

```
function Invoke-BatAsCat { & (Get-Command bat).Source -pp ${Args} }
Set-Alias -Name 'cat' -Value Invoke-BatAsCat
```

The best practice is to use a PowerShell verb for the function name and alias. However, I use `$Args` instead of declaring `param` for brevity.