# Pass Arguments in Powershell's New-Alias like You Can in Bash

Tags: powershell

I want to create a new alias in Powershell, but doing the following:

```
new-alias -name dog -value "C:\Path\To\Dog.exe -flag1 -flag2 arg3"
```

gives me an error about "C:\Path\To\Dog.exe -flag1 -flag2 arg3" not being a valid cmd. I also tried the following:

```
new-alias -name dog -value "C:\Path\To\Dog.exe" -flag1 -flag2 arg3
```

but this caused PS to complain that "-flag1" was not a valid option for the `new-alias` command. 
How do I pass parameters in my alias, like I can do in *nix-land?

Comment: An alias is a "nickname" for a command.  It cannot include parameters.

Comment: If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, also duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166370/how-can-i-write-a-powershell-alias-with-arguments-in-the-middle

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a function that accepts all the parameters you want for your app and then alias that.

```
function Get-Ipconfig
{
    param
    ($Parameter1 = 'all')

    ipconfig.exe "`/$parameter1"

}


Get-Ipconfig

New-Alias -Name gip -Value Get-Ipconfig
```

Answer (score -2):

Try putting your command inside brackets:

```
new-alias -name dog -value (&"C:\Path\To\Dog.exe" -flag1 -flag2 arg3)
```

Comment: Nopes, I get an error: "Unexpected token '-flag1' in expression or statement"

Comment: I forgot the & - updated it now

Comment: This seems to execute the expression within the `(& )` first and use the result as the alias value, correct? Not exactly what I'm trying to do.