# How to add a command line argument to powershell in profile.ps1 for Alias?

Tags: powershell, sublimetext3, alias

I am still quite new to Powershell, but I would like to add my favourite editor into an Alias in Powershell.

I edited the `profile.ps1` in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1` which will run automatically when PowerShells starts.

I tried enter `New-Alias np notepad.exe` which works perfectly everytime I launch PowerShell.

---

However, I would like to use `Sublime Text 3` as my editor. I followed the instructions in this SO page: [How can I write a PowerShell alias with arguments in the middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166370/how-can-i-write-a-powershell-alias-with-arguments-in-the-middle)

The command line I need for `Sublime Text` is `"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" -n [FirstArg]`

Which I come out something like this: `function sublime {  'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -n $args }`

It does not work and I got the error like this:

```
At C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:5 char:72
+ ... lime {  'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -n $args }
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token '-n' in expression or statement.
At C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:5 char:75
+ ... lime {  'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -n $args }
+                                                                   ~~~~~
Unexpected token '$args' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You miss invocation operator `&`.

Comment: @PetSerAl As I'm still quite new to PS, would you please give me an example please? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you ever launch any program with space in their name? If yes, then do the same. If no, then find how to do that. It should be plenty information about this in the Internet.

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes. In Linux, when I want to set an alias with space in path, I could use quotes in it, for example: `export sublime="/path/to/Sublime Text 3"`. Thats why I am confused by `&`. But thanks anyways.

Comment: `'...'` is just a string of characters it doesn't run anything. You need the & to run the thing in the string e.g. `& 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -n $args`

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61374953/1896134

Answer (score 0):

Without being a Sublime user, I suspect this should work:

```
function Start-Sublime {
    param([string]$args)

    $limeArgs = [string]::Empty
    if ($args -ne $null) {
        $limeArgs = $args
    }

    Start-Process "$env:ProgramFiles\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" -n $limeArgs
}

Set-Alias lime Start-Sublime
```

Not the prettiest PowerShell code, but I imagine it will do what you're after. It's a little easier to understand than the cryptic `&` operator is.