# Batch file to change directory run from within powershell does nothing

Tags: powershell, batch-file, working-directory

I have a small "dev.bat" batch file on my PATH which I run to switch to my development project directory in `W:\`. This works fine from CMD but not when run from PowerShell (or PWSH).

I have no other problems running .bat files from PowerShell.

```
PS C:\> type C:\dev.bat
W:
CD W:\dev
PS C:\> dev.bat

me@computer C:\
> W:

me@computer W:\dev
> CD W:\dev

PS C:\> echo "Why did dev.bat not change directory??"
Why did dev.bat not change directory??

PS C:\> W:
PS W:\>
```

No, `cmd /c dev.bat` makes no difference.

Comment: You can change the logic and instead of executing dev.bat inside the powershell, your dev.bat can at the end execute powershell itsefl in directory you want.

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt window and enter `CD /?` you will be able to read the usage information for the command to change directory. When changing drives, you use the **`/D`** option, when just changing paths, you omit the `/D`. In `C:\dev.bat` you should use. **`CD /D "W:\dev"`**, _(the doublequotes aren't necessary, but are best practice)_.

Comment: At the PowerShell prompt, to change directory you use `Set-Location`, _(which has an alias `CD`)_. The method of doing that is generally **`Set-Location -Path "W:\dev"`**, _(`CD "W:\dev"` in its shortened form)_.

Comment: `/d` works only from within CMD and not from within powershell itself. It also only saves me one line in my bat - the point is, `CD` inside a bat doesn't affect the location in the powershell sessions. I also want to just type `dev` and not `Set-Location W:\my\possibly\long\path`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When run from PowerShell, **batch files invariably run in a (`cmd.exe`) *child process*<sup>[1]</sup>**, given that PowerShell itself doesn't understand the batch language.

Changing the working directory in a child process is limited to that child process (and its own children), and has no effect on the calling process; **a child process cannot change the *calling* process' working directory**.

Your only option is to:

- have your batch file *echo* (print) the desired working directory
- capture that path in PowerShell and pass it to `Set-Location`

If you don't want to change your batch file, use the following workaround:

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath (cmd /c 'dev.bat >NUL && cd')

# Or if you want to use the 'cd' alias for Set-Location and 
# are confident that path never has "[" characters in it (so that
# it can't be mistaken for a wildcard expression):
cd (cmd /c 'dev.bat >NUL && cd')
```

---

If batch files needn't be involved at all, and you just want **a convenient way to create custom functions that change to a predefined location (working directory)**, place the following function in your `$PROFILE` file:

```
# Helper function to place in $PROFILE, which generates custom quick-cd
# functions, based on a function name and target directory path.
function New-QuickCD ($Name, $LiteralPath) {
  $funcDef = @"
function global:$Name { Push-Location -LiteralPath "$LiteralPath" } # quick-CD function
"@
  Invoke-Expression $funcDef # define in current session too
  $funcDef >> $PROFILE # append to $PROFILE
}
```

**Note**:

- The generated functions use `Push-Location` rather than `Set-Location` to enable easy returning to the previous location with `Pop-Location` (`popd`).
- For convenience, generated functions are also defined in the *current* session via `Invoke-Expression`<sup>[2]</sup> on creation, so you don't have to reload (dot-source) `$PROFILE` or open a new session before you can call the newly generated function.
- Blindly appending to `$PROFILE` with `>>` means that if you *redefine* a function, the new definition will take effect, but the obsolete previous one will linger in the file, requiring manual cleanup; the comment `# quick-CD function` placed after each generated function is meant to facilitate that - see the bottom section for a more sophisticated version of `New-QuickCD` that updates old definitions in place.
- You can make the function more robust and convenient in a variety of ways: making the parameters mandatory, verifying the path's existence (by default), resolving the path to an absolute one - again, see the bottom section.

E.g., to create a function named `dev` that switches to `W:\dev`, you'd then call:

```
# Generate function 'dev', which switches to 'W:\dev', 
# append it to your $PROFILE file, and also define it in this session:
New-QuickCD dev W:\dev 

# Call it:
dev  # changes the current location to W:\dev; use 'popd' to return.
```

---

#### More robust, flexible `New-QuickCD` function:

It improves on the above version as follows:

- It makes the parameters mandatory.
- It verifies the existence of the target directory path.
- It defines the functions with support for a `-PrintOnly` switch that merely prints the function's target directory, without changing to it.
- It resolves a relative path to an absolute one first, so that you can run `New-QuickCD foo .` to define a function that switches to the absolute path of the current location.
- When you *redefine* a function, the previous definition is automatically updated:

  - In order to enable this functionality `$PROFILE` is rewritten as a whole, using the `>` redirection operator.
  - To *remove* functions, you must still edit `$PROFILE` manually.
- It comes with comment-based help; run `help New-QuickCD -Examples`, for instance.

```
function New-QuickCD {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Creates a custom quick-CD function.

  .DESCRIPTION
    Creates a custom quick-CD function and appends it your $PROFILE file.

    Such a function changes to a fixed location (directory) stored inside the 
    function, specified at creation time to allow for quickly changing to
    frequently used directories using a short name.

    For convenience, a newly created function is also defined for the running
    session (not just for all future sessions).

    The quick-CD functions use Push-Location to change location, which
    enables you to easily return to the previously active location with
    Pop-Location (popd).

    To determine what location a given quick-CD function *would* change to,
    invoke it with the -PrintOnly switch.

  .PARAMETER FunctionName
  The name of the quick-CD function to define.

  .PARAMETER DirectoryPath
  The literal path of the directory the quick-CD function should change to.
  If given a relative path, it is resolved to an absolute one first.
  For convenience, you may specify a *file* path, in which case that file's
  parent path is used.

  .NOTES
    Your $PROFILE file is recreated every time you use this function, using the
    > redirection operator, so as to support updating functions in place.

    To *remove* a quick-CD function, edit $PROFILE manually.

  .EXAMPLE
    New-QuickCD dev W:\dev

    Adds a 'dev' function to $PROFILE, which on invocation changes the current
    location to W:\dev
    * Call just 'dev' to change to W:\dev. Use popd to return to the previous
      location.
    * Call 'dev -PrintOnly' to print what location function 'dev' *would*
      change to.

  .EXAMPLE
    New-QuickCD proj .

    Adds a 'proj' function to $PROFILE, which on invocation changes to the 
    the location that is current at the time of calling New-QuickCd.

  #>
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $FunctionName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $DirectoryPath
  )

  Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

  # Resolve the path to a full path. Fail if it doesn't exist.
  $fullPath = (Resolve-Path -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $DirectoryPath).Path
  # As a courtesy, if the path is a *file*, we use its parent path instead.
  if (Test-Path -PathType Leaf $fullPath) {
    $fullPath = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($fullPath)
  }

  # Define a comment that identifies the functions we add to $PROFILE as
  # quick-CD functions.
  $idComment = '<# quick-CD function generated with New-QuickCD #>'

  # Generate the new function's source code...
  #  * on a *single line*, which enables easy filtering when updating $PROFILE below
  #  * with a distinctive comment at the end of the line that identifies the
  #    function as a quick-CD function.
  #  * with the global: scope specifier, which makes it easier to call the
  #    same definition with Invok-Expression to make the function available in the
  #    current session too.
  $newFuncDef = @"
$idComment function global:$FunctionName { param([switch] `$PrintOnly) if (`$PrintOnly) { "$fullPath" } else { Push-Location -LiteralPath "$fullPath" } }
"@
  # ... define it in the current session (doing this *before* updating $PROFILE ensures early exit if the function name is invalid)
  Invoke-Expression $newFuncDef
  # ... and update $PROFILE:
  # Get the current content of $PROFILE
  [string] $currentProfileContent =  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $PROFILE)  { Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $PROFILE }
  # Try to replace an existing definition.
  $newProfileContent = $currentProfileContent -replace ('(?m)^{0} function global:{1} .+$' -f [regex]::Escape($idComment), [regex]::Escape($FunctionName)), $newFuncDef
  if (-not $currentProfileContent -or $newProfileContent -ceq $currentProfileContent) { # Profile didn't exist or nothing was replaced -> we must append the new definition.
    $newProfileContent = $newProfileContent.TrimEnd() + [Environment]::NewLine * 2 + $newFuncDef
  }
  # Write the file.
  $newProfileContent > $PROFILE

}
```

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, batch files run *in-process* when invoked from `cmd.exe`, analogous to how PowerShell runs its `*.ps1` scripts in-process. 
 POSIX-like shells such as Bash, on the other hand, by default run their scripts in a child process, except when sourcing is used (`.`, `source`)</sup>

<sup>[2] While this is a safe use of `Invoke-Expression`, it [should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another  simple way to do that is create  a dev.ps1 (PowerShell Script file) rather batch file, whith the follow code `Set-Location -Path "W:\dev"`

Note: batch file runs on CMD process as a child process even if you runs it on powershell

Answer (score -1):

@mkelement is correct: there is no simple way to do this from a .bat file on your path - that is old school. The proper PowerShell way is to create an alias to a function which does what you want.

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46372433/279255) my solution is:

**Step 1: Create a reusable function to make an alias**:

```bsh
PS> echo 'function myAlias {
    $g=[guid]::NewGuid();
    $alias = $args[0]; $commands = $args[1];
    echo "function G$g { $commands }; New-Alias -Force $alias G$g">>$profile
};'>>$profile
```

Re-start powershell (to load the above function) and then define your `dev` shortcut as follows:

**Step 2: Create a `dev` shortcut/alias which gets you where you want to be:**

```bsh
PS> myAlias dev "Set-Location W:\dev"
```

**Step 3: Happily use `dev`**

```bsh
PS C:\> dev
PS W:\dev>
```

Comment: The idea to create custom quick-CD _functions_ on demand is a neat one, but I recommend against calling them _aliases_, given that in PowerShell aliases can only ever be aliases for command _names_, and cannot not wrap entire calls _with arguments_; there's no reason to involve alias functionality at all, so the generator function can be greatly simplified - please see my updated answer (though note that my solution is focused just on creating custom-CD functions and therefore accepts just the target path, not the whole `Set-Location` call - it's easy to generalize, though).

Comment: While I appreciate the question and the _idea_ behind your solution, I think the terminology confusion and the convoluted implementation of the generator function are ultimately more harmful than beneficial to future readers.

Comment: You are right that I have added more abstraction than is strictly required to solve my problem and that your answer is the correct answer to why what I was trying can't work. My focus is on a quick, pragmatic, it just works, way to alias command shortcuts (in the non-technical sense) and not necessarily a long function which, if correctly imported, will do amazing things. I therefore disagree with your opinion of not using aliases here: that's exactly what Aliases are for.

Comment: What you're looking for is a _command wrapper_; how that is _technically implemented_ varies by language: in PowerShell, you need a _function_ - and _only_ a function, whereas in Bash you can do it with an _alias_ (within limits). Using the term _alias_ loosely, even though it has a distinct technical meaning in PowerShell, is ill-advised. The shortest expression of your intent is a function such as `function dev { Set-Location W:\Dev }` - no alias needed; it is what the `New-QuickCD` function in my answer creates - no unnecessary detours via auto-named functions and aliases.