# The term 'mysql -uroot -p' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell, scripting, alias

i've been trying to add "mysql.exe -uroot -p" as an **alias** in **powershell** but everytime i save the file and start powershell it throws me this error.
i **have** included mysql in my environment path and it works fine on its own,
just that i dont wanna type a long command everytime i login.

```
mysqlRoot: The term 'mysql.exe -uroot -p' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

*things ive tried so far in the powershell profile:*

- new-alias mysqlRoot "mysql.exe -uroot -p"
- new-alias mysqlRoot mysql.exe -uroot -p   *[without quotes basically]*
- new-alias mysqlRoot "mysql -uroot -p"
- copied the 'mysql -uroot -p' from the command line ,it worked fine.

**please tell me what I'm doing wrong,definitely noob here so please go easy on me**

Comment: or this one: [How can I write a PowerShell alias with arguments in the middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166370/how-can-i-write-a-powershell-alias-with-arguments-in-the-middle)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, sorry for not checking