# Creating Alias in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, alias

I want to create an alias for 'jupyter notebook' in windows powershell. I ran the following command:

```
Set-Alias -Name jup -Value jupyter notebook
```

It triggered following error:

```
Set-Alias : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'notebook'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Alias -Name jup -Value jupyter notebook
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Alias], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAliasCommand
```

Can someone please help me fix it?

Comment: if "jupyter notebook" works from command prompt , then you should try Set-Alias -Name jup -Value "jupyter notebook" in quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write a PowerShell alias with arguments in the middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166370/how-can-i-write-a-powershell-alias-with-arguments-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the fact that to start "jupyter notebook" you start the exe "jupyter" with parameter "notebook". To do so you have to create a function :

```
function jup {
    jupyter notebook
}
```

Then you can put this function in one of your [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2).