# Powershell: Have working Aliases for longer commands with parameters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write some PowerShell aliases in my profile.ps1 file. The problem is that I can not get commands with a variable number of parameters to work properly.

For example, I want to have an alias that links "kg" to "kubectl get", which is followed by a resource and sometimes an option. So "kg pods -A" and "kg pod" should both work afterwords.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166370/how-can-i-write-a-powershell-alias-with-arguments-in-the-middle), I need to define a function that can be seen below, my problem is that it ignores all arguments after the first. So "kg pods -A" returns the result of "kg pods".
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell) explains how to pass multiple arguments to a function, up it does not work for some reason.
(I am using Powershell in Cmder if this is relevant).
Could it be that the "-" causes an issue?

The relevant part of the "profile.ps1":

```
Function get ($restOfLine, $restOfLine2) { kubectl get $restOfLine $restOfLine2}
Set-Alias kg get
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you explicitly declare parameters in a function, PowerShell will attempt to *bind* input arguments to those parameters, by parsing the command invocation expression and treating any sequence starting with `-` as a parameter name.

Remove the parameters and pass `$args` directly to avoid this interference:

```
function get { kubectl get @args }
Set-Alias kg get
```

`kg post -A` will now pass `post` and `-A` to `kubectl` as-is